# Overriding pure virtual functions such that derived class is not abstract

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, interface, radix

Suppose I have an abstract base class

```
class base
{
public:
virtual void function() = 0;
};
```

followed by a derived class

```
class derived_1 : public base
{
public:
... function() ...;
};
```

How could I overload the above function if I do not want it to be defined but I wish for derived_1 not to be abstract, so I can instantiate it?

These classes are then followed by another class

```
class derived_2 : public base, public derived_1
{
public:
void function()
{
// What my function does
}
```

Basically, I wish for both derived classes to be instantiated but I want them both to use the base class as an interface whilst derived_2 inherits derived_1.  The pure virtual function overload to be used in the main code needs to be in the derived_2 class.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can't have a non-abstract class with pure virtual functions.

Comment: @tkausl can you think of a suitable workaround for this so that I can instantiate derived_1?

Comment: What would you expect to happen when you call `function` on a instance of `derived_1`?

Comment: I don't wish for anything to happen.

Comment: Then define `function` with an empty body.

Comment: That is what I did, I just wondered whether there was a better way

Comment: In your code, `derived_1` is not derived from anything.

Comment: @Jasper Kent it is now, sorry. It should have been.

Comment: If you really want to do this you can either implement it with an empty body or throw an exception (probably less error-prone). However, it is likely that this is not the correct structure if you are asking this question. (Maybe you should use two different base classes?)

Comment: Also, just a tiny note: you don't actually need `derived_2` to inherit from both `base` and `derived_1` (just `derived_1` will do the same, but is cleaner)

Answer (score 4):

Defining a function as a pure virtual means that it must be implemented by the subclasses in order for them to not be abstract. There is not alot of information about your program here, but if you need to do something like that, maybe you should consider changing the structure of your program. The fact that you're defining a function to be pure virtual and not needing it in a derived classe that has to be concrete, that implys that the program is not well designed. Anyways, if you still want to instantiate from `derived_1` anyways, you can just provide an empty implementation for `function()` and that should work. But my suggestion is that you probably need more that one interface. Let base not have the function `function` and instead define it in an another interface, and let `derived_2` inherit from `derived_1` and also implement the interface that contains the function `function`.